# Dynamically created dropdownlist wont trigger

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hey guys I'm having a hard time making my drop-down list trigger with dynamically created value options in it.

```
                <label>Year Level Advisory: </label>
                <select id="org-subject-advisory-level" name="subject_level">

                </select>



                <label>Subjects: </label>
                <select id="subjects-list">

                </select>
```

jquery ajax:

```
function get_my_advisory(){

     $.ajax({                
            url:'func_students.php',
            type:'POST',
            dataType:'json',
            data:{'func_num':'4'},
            success: function (data){

               $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                   var options = "<option value="+data[i].sec_level+">"+data[i].sec_level+"</option>";

                     $('#org-subject-advisory-level').append(options);
                   }); 

          }
    });
  }
get_my_advisory();


$('#org-subject-advisory-level').on("change", function(){

    var advisory_year_level = $('#org-subject-advisory-level').val();

alert(advisory_year_level);
    $('#subjects-list').html("");

    $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'add_subject.php',
               dataType:'json',
                   data:{'func_numbr':'9','year_level':advisory_year_level},
                success:function (data){
                  $.each(data, function(i, item) {

                   html = "<option value="+data[i].subj_id+">"+data[i].subj_name+"</option>";

                     $('#subjects-list').append(html);
                   });
                }

                });



  });

  $('#org-subject-advisory-level').trigger("change");
```

The trigger works, but it return a null value on alert, I wonder why is that happening. Hoping for your help guys. I'm a newbie in jquery and php. Thanks in advance

Comment: What "alert" ? I don't see it in your code.

Comment: i update it. please refresh

Comment: The possible reason for the null value is that these functions are all executed at DOM ready. Your ajax call may not have been completed yet, and therefore, when you build the change function and trigger it, the values haven't been set yet. If you place `$('#org-subject-advisory-level').trigger("change");` within the `success` function of your `ajax()`, I bet you'll see a value.

Comment: Move this `$('#org-subject-advisory-level').trigger("change");` just below this `$('#org-subject-advisory-level').append(options);` and see if this gets you the value you are looking for.

Comment: oh! thanks dude i havent realize that one. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine, but the initial `.trigger` (the one at the bottom) is done before any options are loaded at all.  The initial ajax request will most likely not have completed before that code is reached.  Move

```
$('#org-subject-advisory-level').trigger("change");
```

to inside the `success:` callback for the initial ajax call and the first `<option>` value that is appended should be what is alerted.

Answer (score 0):

AS @Ohgodway has mentioned in the comment... mostly your ajax call will not be completebefore the trigger is called so call your trigger function inside ajax success function when the select option is appended.

Try this:

```
 $.ajax({                
        url:'func_students.php',
        type:'POST',
        dataType:'json',
        data:{'func_num':'4'},
        success: function (data){

           $.each(data, function(i, item) {
               var options = "<option value="+data[i].sec_level+">"+data[i].sec_level+"</option>";

                 $('#org-subject-advisory-level').append(options);
               }); 

         $('#org-subject-advisory-level').trigger("change");

      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As posted above trigger your change event inside success callback or complete callback of jQuery ajax.

But before you trigger change event make sure to select any option by default. For some browser first one is default selected, but for some browser nothing is selected which will return null.
So better you select any of option explicitly.
like

```
$('#org-subject-advisory-level').find('option:last').attr('selected',true);
```

Further more I will suggest you to change your looping method, use native for loop instead of jquery each.
You can get little bit efficiency by optimizing your code like

```
 $.each(data, function(i, item) {

 html = "<option value="+data[i].subj_id+">"+data[i].subj_name+"</option>";

 $('#subjects-list').append(html);
 });
```

to

```
var html=[];
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
html.push("<option value="+data[i].subj_id+">"+data[i].subj_name+"</option>");
}
$('#subjects-list').append(html.join(''));
```